# empty object of std::string literal passed by forward reference in MS VS 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdstring

Can you, please, explain me a strange bahavior with forward references in MS VS 2017? Constructors for rvalue std::strings (a2 & a3) get the empty strings.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

class A {
    string text{};
public:
    template <typename T,
              typename = typename enable_if_t< !is_base_of_v<A, decay_t<T>> && 
                                               !is_integral_v<remove_reference_t<T>> >>
    explicit A(T&& str) : text(forward<T>(str)) { 
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    explicit A(int x) : text(to_string(x)) {}
};

int main()
{
    string s = "hello"s;
    A a1(s);
    A a2(" world"s); // why?
    A a3(string(" world")); // why?
    A a4(" world");
    A a5(34);
    A a6(a2);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::forward<T>(x)` is a conditional move - if `T` is not an lvalue reference, `x` will be moved. In the case of `a2` and `a3`, your `str` is moved into the data member `text` before printing it. When printing it, anything can happen as the state of `str` is unspecified.